# How to retrieve all syscalls made by a process running within .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am pretty new to .NET. Recently I have come up with a project where I have to retrieve all syscalls called by a particular process, to charecterize the process. I'd like to know the namespace and methods that can help me get this info.By using syscalls what exactly i mean is the system processes addressed by any application during its course.Say a process need to start a network connection uses 'connect' call.I need to trace all such calls used by a process

Comment: Are you doing this with Mono or .NET? Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm using visual studio on windows...

Comment: This is a very difficult problem. You're probably better off using something like APIMonitor http://www.apimonitor.com/ to gather data, and then process that data with a C# program.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "syscalls"?

Comment: Do you think i can do this using wmi

Answer (score 0):

your not going to be able to do this in .net and your not going to be able to do it with out a good handle on windows fundamentals. You are going to need either a third party tool that does the monitoring or you are going to need to write your own hooks using something like [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) which is a non trivial task.